# Gradle not aware of Java syntax errors?

Tags: java, gradle, configuration

When I run my `"build"` Gradle task it *is* downloading all my dependencies as expected, however it does not seem to pick up on the fact that I have a *Java Syntax error.*

I have **purposely** created a syntax error with a missing `;` to check this.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

**Java class:**

```
package client;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import util.HibernateUtil;
import entity.Message;


public class HelloWorldClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

                Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
                session.beginTransaction();

                Message message = new Message( "Hello World with Hibernate & JPA Annotations" ) //note no ;

                session.save(message);

                session.getTransaction().commit();
                session.close();

    }
}
```

Build.gradle:

```
group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "src.client.HelloWorldClient"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.38'
    compile 'antlr:antlr:2.7.7'
    compile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'
    compile 'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final'
    compile 'org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.18.1-GA'
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.3.GA'
    compile 'org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1'
    compile 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final'
}
```

**Congifuration:**

[image]

**Project Structure:**

[image]

**Output after dependencies downloaded:**

```
All projects evaluated.
Selected primary task 'build' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':compileJava', task ':processResources', task ':classes', task ':jar', task ':startScripts', task ':distTar', task ':distZip', task ':assemble', task ':compileTestJava', task ':processTestResources', task ':testClasses', task ':test', task ':check', task ':build']
:compileJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:compileJava
Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files.
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:processResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:processResources
Skipping task ':processResources' as it has no source files.
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:processResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:classes (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:classes
Skipping task ':classes' as it has no actions.
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:classes (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:jar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:jar
Skipping task ':jar' as it is up-to-date (took 0.004 secs).
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:jar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.006 secs.
:startScripts (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:startScripts
Skipping task ':startScripts' as it is up-to-date (took 0.065 secs).
:startScripts UP-TO-DATE
:startScripts (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.067 secs.
:distTar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:distTar
Skipping task ':distTar' as it is up-to-date (took 0.008 secs).
:distTar UP-TO-DATE
:distTar (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.014 secs.
:distZip (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:distZip
Skipping task ':distZip' as it is up-to-date (took 0.009 secs).
:distZip UP-TO-DATE
:distZip (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.016 secs.
:assemble (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:assemble
Skipping task ':assemble' as it has no actions.
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:assemble (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:compileTestJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:compileTestJava
Skipping task ':compileTestJava' as it has no source files.
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:processTestResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:processTestResources
Skipping task ':processTestResources' as it has no source files.
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
:testClasses (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:testClasses
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:test (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:test
Skipping task ':test' as it has no source files.
:test UP-TO-DATE
:test (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:check (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:check
Skipping task ':check' as it has no actions.
:check UP-TO-DATE
:check (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
:build (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) started.
:build
Skipping task ':build' as it has no actions.
:build UP-TO-DATE
:build (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.316 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
22:06:01: External task execution finished 'build --info'.
```

**New Project Structure:**

[image]

Comment: What does it do after it downloads the dependencies?

Comment: Please see my update with added output from after dependencies are downloaded

Comment: This might help: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-troubleshoot-when-build-task-isnt-running-my-project/2363

Comment: From what I can see it is stating that I need the application plugin, which I aready have? Sorry I am quite new to Gradle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any source files under `src/main/java`. Move the client, domain, entity packages under there and you'll get your compile error :)

Comment: Thanks, Please see my updates structure in my edit at the bottom. I have done this but  am still getting the "Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files" error?

Comment: @java123999 Your `src/main/java` directory is still empty.

Comment: Thank you I have sorted this issue now , silly mistake!

Answer (score 1):

> Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files.

Move your sources to `src/main/java` or adjust your build file.

See 23.4 https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Comment: Please see my updates structure in my edit at the bottom. I have done this but  am still getting the "Skipping task ':compileJava' as it has no source files" error?

Comment: @java123999 it's still not in the `java` directory. You can have a project that has for example `src/main/java`, `src/main/scala`, `src/main/python` and so on.

Comment: @java123999 your xml files could btw go into `src/main/resources` if you like that better. Not sure what the exact differences are though.

Comment: Thank you, my code now compiles but I am getting an error that one of the packages from dependencies does not exist?

Comment: @java123999 I can't look onto your monitor, you'll have to be more specific than "an error" :)